# Have two programs use and write to same device (in /dev/snd)

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to open a MIDI card (character special file) in /dev/snd that is already being used by Application 1.
Unless I use O_NONBLOCK (brings up resource busy error), the open() function hangs, waiting forever the resource to become free.

Is it possible to open the file in parallel? I simply need to write a few bytes of hexadecimal to it and that's it; the other application must remain running.

e.g. of what I would like to do:

```
Application 1
open("/dev/snd/midiC1D0", O_NONBLOCK);
... application continues its operations in the background ...
```

_

```
Application 2
int fd = open("dev/snd/midiC1D0", FLAGS);
unsigned char ch = 0xFF;
write(fd, &ch, 1);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Are you the author of both apps? If so you could introduce a way for one app to send data to the other using e.g. sockets and then forward to the MIDI device as needed.

Comment: People have written "sound daemons" for _exactly_ this purpose, to let applications connect to the daemon, and then the daemon mix or multiplex the channels and connect to the underlying hardware driver. If the driver isn't written to allow multiple connections, you can't fix that without rewriting it.

Comment: The driver seems to be built by ALSA, and perhaps you're right it could be coded to refuse multiple connections (https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html#open-and-release).

Comment: Are you sure the other application is using `/dev/snd/midiC1D0` directly rather than via some higher level audio API such as e.g. [`openAL`](https://openal.org/)?

Comment: Yes, as it opens using the snd_rawmidi_open() function. Using amidi to send the Application 2 message also fails in the same way: cannot open /dev/snd/midiC1D0 because resource is busy.